# Disabling onscreen keyboard when laptop mode (Acer Alpha Switch 12)

Tags: laptop, acer, touchscreen, onscreen-keyboard

I have managed to get Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 working on my Acer Alpha Switch 12. Beside some minor annoying issues I got the problem that the on screen keyboard pops up for text fields even if my physical keyboard is attached to the device. Is it possible to simply disable the on screen keyboard when the keyboard is attached and the other way around? I read something about acpid but I have to admit I am not really familiar with it.

Is there any simple solution?

Answer (score 0):

For a few years its not possible to toggle it, you can disable it entirely

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1326/block-caribou/?c=58652